# Gluten-free and egg-free yeast bread

Tags: bread, gluten-free

I am working on a recipe that uses gluten-free flour and cauliflower flour. I am having trouble getting the bread to be like a bread and not an edible brick. Any suggestions on proofing and baking temperature? I can not use any baking soda/powder or xanthan gum. The combined flour weight is 3 lbs, and water is 2 lbs.

Comment: Can you use psyllium husk?  Egg free made me think of aquafaba, and that led me to find : https://www.asaucykitchen.com/gluten-free-vegan-french-bread/

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide your ingredient list, it would be easier to give suggestions based on your formulation.
If you are making a straight dough gluten free bread, I would recommend temperature 80-100F and humidity 60-80%. The proofing time totally depends on proofing temperature and your formulation (ex. sugar/yeast).
Baking temperature also depends on what type of flour you are using. Starches/flour gel at different temp, so it is hard to say what is the optimum temp as per your recipe. Where you located also matters, if you live in high altitudes place, baking needs slightly higher temperature.
I would suggest you to start with 350F baking, if the bread seems under-baked after an hour, you can increase the temperature sequentially by 25F.
I also agree with Joe, using psyllium husk is much better choice than xanthan for bread recipe.